# Found a bizarre looking capacitor

Tags: capacitor, identification, components, surface-mount

[image]
[image]

I found these capacitors from a broken test equipment in my lab. I guess these are capacitors since the component label starts with 'c'. But I'm not 100% sure what they are exactly. I've also noticed that these components are lifted up from the surface. I also couldn't understand the purpose of doing this. Possibly to reduce parasitic capacitance further? Not sure...

If anyone knows what this component is exactly and why they are lifted up from the surface, please leave comments and share your knowledge with me. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe a wide bandwidth isolation barrier. What does the board do? Doesn’t look quite top tier quality.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany This is a remote head for the sampling scope module (86118A). Just curious: why do you think this is not a top-tier quality board? If one wants to improve, what portions do you think needs improvement?

Comment: Registration on the PCB is not very good. Maybe it's just old though.

Comment: maybe they are some type of a "run hours" timer ... there is a color gradient along the length

Comment: They look like made with dual-sided alumina dielectric PCB. The _gradient_ is just because the upper layer is connected only to one side contact, and I expect the bottom side to be symmetrical. Maybe shaped to fit a 15mm standard distance between legs for PTH caps, like MKT/MKP, though with indeed a very slim profile. A few picoFarads?